# In symfony : how can i display two module in one page in admin-part

Tags: symfony-1.4

in symfony:
i have a module for Article and another for Comments 
i want to display the two modules in one page << back end >>

thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way of doing this. You can merge a form in another one by using the mergeForm() method, or embed one by using the embedForm() method. Here's the [link](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/10). Search for the methods on the page to see a clear example of user. I hope this helps.

Comment: I think that there is no "automatic" way to do it. If you want to do this, you must rewrite modules manually. Everything depends on the design of your app and your current task.